# Can I run a Docker container to use in another Google Cloud Build step?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, docker, rspec, google-cloud-build

I'd like to run a fresh MySQL instance in a Docker Container as a Cloud Build, and then access that MySQL DB in a later step to run Unit Tests against.   Is this possible?  [It appears as if I can run a Docker Container in a build step, but the step doesn't complete until the Container exists](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/tree/master/docker#run-a-docker-image).  I'd like this MySQL container to remain running until after the final build step completes.

FWIW I'd like to use this on a Ruby on Rails project to run rspec tests.  I currently use a CloudSQL instance to run tests against, but it's pretty slow, even though the same tests run quickly locally.  Changing the machine-type for the Cloud Builder to something powerful didn't help, so I assume latency is my biggest killer, which is why I want to try a peer Container MySQL instance instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out there are at least 2 ways to skin this cat:

1. Use `docker-compose` cloud builder to spin up multiple containers in 1 step: MySQL and a test runner.   The downside here is the step will never complete unless since MySQL will run in the background and never exit.  I suppose one could write a wrapper to cause it to die after a few minutes.
2. You can actually start a container with `-d` in an early build step and ensure it's on the `cloudbuild` docker network, and then later steps can connect to it if they're also on the `cloudbuild` network.  Essentially the Mysql step will "complete" quickly as it just starts the server in daemon mode then continues to next build step.  Later, the test runner will run tests against the fresh DB and its build step completes when tests are actually done.

I went with option 2, and my 16-min unit tests (run against CloudSQL in same region) shrunk down to 1.5mins using the dockerized MySQL server.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't do this. Each step is independent and you can't run a background step.

My solution here is to have the MySQL in the same step as your unit test, and to run MySQL as a background process, in the same step. Quite boring (because you have to install and run MySQL in your step) but I haven't better solution.

For an easier use, you can [create your own custom builder for Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/cloud-builders)

Comment: Thanks - I think you're right.  I notice there is a `docker-compose` Cloud Builder, which would make this pretty easy https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/tree/master/docker-compose