# Is there a way to run the Datastore Emulator in Cloud Build?

Tags: go, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-build

I am trying to run some Go unit tests in Cloud Build each time that a PR is submitted to a particular branch on my repository. The problem is that my unit tests rely on a connection to the Datastore Emulator [1](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator). Here is an example of how I setup the emulator before running the unit tests. I have a `*_test.go` file with the `init` function like this:

```
    func init() {
        // Set up port for Datastore Emulator
        err := os.Setenv("DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST", "localhost:8000")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Error setting up Port for DS Emulator: %v", err)
        }

        // Check if Datastore Emulator is running on port 8000
        _, err = net.Dial("tcp", "localhost:8000")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Please ensure you have Datastore Emulator running on port 8000 before running tests: %v", err)
        }

        dsClient, err = datastore.NewClient(ctx, mockCfg.GCP.ProjectID)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Error creating datastore client: %v", err)
        }
        defer dsClient.Close()
    }
```

Locally I run the emulator with the cloud-sdk using:

```bash
gcloud --project=dsemu beta emulators datastore start \
    --host-port 0.0.0.0:8000 \
    --no-store-on-disk \
    --use-firestore-in-datastore-mode
```

The tests run fine locally, and I use the following `cloudbuild.yaml` to execute the tests in Cloud Build:

```
steps:
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args:
      - run
      - '-d'
      - '--network=cloudbuild'
      - '--name=dsemu'
      - google/cloud-sdk
      - gcloud
      - '--project=dsemu'
      - beta
      - emulators
      - datastore
      - start
      - '--host-port=0.0.0.0:8000'
      - '--no-store-on-disk'
      - '--use-firestore-in-datastore-mode'
  - name: jwilder/dockerize
    args:
      - dockerize
      - '-timeout=60s'
      - '-wait=tcp://dsemu:8000'
  - name: 'golang:1.19'
    env:
      - 'DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=dsemu:8000'
    args:
      - go
      - test
      - ./...
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args:
      - rm
      - '--force'
      - dsemu
timeout: 600s
```

This is where the issue arises. The tests are unable to connect to the `cloudbuild` network to complete. The build reaches the timeout of 10m and fails. Any ideas of what could be wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65693376/can-i-run-a-docker-container-to-use-in-another-google-cloud-build-step